# How to calculate gain (op-amp)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, gain

This is a microphone pre-amp circuit (from an old project):

[image]

How do I calculate its gain, especially in dB?

Comment: so it's simpy 68k/680?

Comment: \$20 \log 100 = 40\$.

Comment: @user263983 - for amplifiers/preamplifiers like this, gain is 20 dB/x10. Not 10.

Comment: The \$100\:\text{nF}\$ caps are only negligible (\$10\:\Omega\$, let's say) at about \$160\:\text{kHz}\$. Since this is a microphone pre-amp, that fact makes the intended pickup frequency range matter. If [human voice only](https://voicefoundation.org/health-science/voice-disorders/anatomy-physiology-of-voice-production/understanding-voice-production/), for example, we may be talking 300 Hz or lower! (\$X\ge 5\:\text{k}\Omega\$) If for common sounds, 5-8 kHz on the high end. (\$X\ge 200\:\Omega\$.) So what's the microphone for?

Answer (score 6):

You compute the gain of that circuit by scraping away bits of it until it looks like a basic OP-amp circuit; then you look at the textbook gain for that circuit.

R27 and R29 are there to provide a pseudo-ground, at about 1/2 the supply voltage.  C33 may or may not contribute to the frequency response of the circuit -- I'm going to pretend it doesn't.  So make a "pseudo-ground" in your head and connect it to the junction of R27, R28, R29, and C33.  Now pretend that C51 is a short, and that the microphone is a perfect AC source.

It's starting to look like it may be a bog-standard non-inverting amplifier.

C34 is an open circuit for DC, but a perfect ground path for AC -- so call it a short to your pseudo-ground.  What's left *is* a bog-standard non-inverting amplifier, with the gain set by R30 and R32.  So the gain is $$A = 1 + \frac{R_{32}}{R_{30}} \simeq 101.$$

Round that to 100 -- that's 40dB, so that's your gain in dB.

Comment: Is the gain more like  \$A  = 1 + \frac {R_{32}||R_{31}} {R_{30}} \$ ?

Comment: @AmitM yes, but R32 is marked NU, probably "Not Used"

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, C34 acts as a higher resistance at low freqencies (below 1/(2.pi.R.C) = 1/(2 * 3.14 * 680 * 100n) = 2.3 kHz. Thus gain rolls off towards 1 at frequencies below 2 kHz (the 100 nF likely isn't very accurate, so no need to calculate more accurately).

The 2.2 uF input capacitor also rolls off gain to 0 starting from (2.2 uF & 4k7 // 4k7 ==> 31 Hz.